# Custom BoxWhisker Plot

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, charts

I’d like to figure out how I can show my entire dataset overlaid on a box whisker plot.

```
data = {{0.763983, -1.11426, 1.05153, -0.0369066, 1.1571, 0.834856, 0.146695,
0.100646, 2.69399, 0.425281}, {0.506237, 1.05127, 1.58117, 
0.976295, 1.62204, 1.39005, 1.62387, 1.36098, 1.83858, 
0.709489}, {-1.62786, 0.947744, 4.50628, 0.444416, 1.30947, 0.60594,
0.890642, 4.04505, 4.57667, 0.781394}}
```

The following allows me to show `Outliers` overlaid on the plot. How would I go about overlaying all of the datapoint on the plot?

```
BoxWhiskerChart[data, {"Notched", {"MedianMarker", Blue}, {"Outliers", 
"\[EmptySmallCircle]", Red}},ChartLabels -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}]
```

Comment: `Show[BoxWhiskerChart[data], 
 ListPlot[MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #1} &, data, {2}]]]`

Comment: Thanks this works well…! Still learning the intricacies of Mathematica’s plotting routines

Comment: Belisarius, can you explain how the MapIndexed trick works. I seem to have a hard time understanding it. Would appreciate some help…..

Comment: Can you post an answer so that I can acknowledge this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is:

```
Show[BoxWhiskerChart[data], ListPlot[MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #1} &, data, {2}]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`MapIndexed` operates just like `Map`but gives you a second argument which is the index of the list element you're getting each time.

Comment: I don’t still quite get {#2[[1]], #1} part of it… I know they stand for slot sequences but still don’t see how they map to the data…

Comment: @Pam Try `MapIndexed[f, {a,b}]` to see that `#2[[1]]` takes values `1, 2` and `#1` takes values `a, b`

Answer (score 2):

You can overlay your data and `BoxWhiskerChart` using a custom `ChartStyleFunction`. The first example `ceF1` combines built-in `ChartElementDataFunction["BoxWhisker"]` with the graphics primitives obtained from `ListPlot` of the data. The second and third examples use the buit-in functions `"PointDensity"` and `"LineDensity"` in place of `ListPlot`.

```
ceF1 = {PointSize[.015], ChartElementDataFunction["BoxWhisker"][##], 
    ListPlot[Thread[{Mean[#[[1]]], #2}], PlotStyle -> 
       Darker[Darker@Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"]]][[1]]} &;

ceF2 = {PointSize[.05], FaceForm[Opacity[.3]], 
    ChartElementDataFunction["PointDensity", "PointStyle" -> 
     Directive[Darker[Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"]],  PointSize[Large]]][##], 
   Opacity[.8], ChartElementDataFunction["BoxWhisker"][##]} &;

ceF3 = {Thick, Darker[Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"]], 
    ChartElementDataFunction["LineDensity"][##], Opacity[.8], 
    ChartElementDataFunction["BoxWhisker"][##]} &;
```

Examples:

```
Panel[BoxWhiskerChart[data, {"Notched", {"MedianMarker", Blue}, 
  {"Outliers", "\[EmptyCircle]", Directive[15, Bold, Red]}}, 
  ChartLabels -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}, ChartStyle -> 63, 
  ImageSize -> 320, ChartElementFunction -> ToExpression[#]], 
  Style["ChartElementFunction->" <> #, 18, "Panel"], Top] & /@ 
   {"ceF1", "ceF2", "ceF3"} // Row
```

[image]